# Concatenar dos diccionarios sin repetir campo

Tags: python, python-3.x

Tengo dos diccionarios con las mismas llaves, un valor de llave en común y los demás valores diferentes, como sigue:

```
Colombia = {'stats': [{'value': [{'wins': 3}, {'ties': 1}, {'defeats': 2}], 'team': 'Colombia'}],
            'cup': 41}

Brasil =  {'stats': [{'value': [{'wins': 3}, {'ties': 2}, {'defeats': 1}], 'team': 'Brasil'}],
           'cup': 41}
```

Y necesito obtener un diccionario conjunto de la siguiente forma:

```
{'stats': [[{'value': [{'wins': 3}, {'ties': 1}, {'defeats': 2}], 'team': 'Colombia'}],
           [{'value': [{'wins': 3}, {'ties': 2}, {'defeats': 1}], 'team': 'Brasil'}]],
 'cup': 41}
```

Como se ve, necesito concatenar los dos diccionarios de forma que la llave `stats`contenga el contenido de dicha llave en ambos diccionarios, pero sin cambiar la llave `cup`.

He encontrado un código en Stack en inglés pero concatena el contenido de las dos llaves  duplicándose el contenido de la llave `cup`y obteniendo esto:

```
{'stats': [[{'value': [{'wins': 3}, {'ties': 1}, {'defeats': 2}], 'team': 'Colombia'}],
           [{'value': [{'wins': 3}, {'ties': 2}, {'defeats': 1}], 'team': 'Brasil'}]],
 'cup': [41, 41]}
```

cosa que no debe hacer, no debe hacer.

El código en cuestión es este:

```
for key in (colombia.keys() | brasil.keys()):
    if key in colombia: result.setdefault(key, []).append(colombia[key])
    if key in brasil: result.setdefault(key, []).append(brasil[key])
```

Existe alguna manera de sólo concatenar la llave `stats`de ambos diccionarios? Hay alguna forma genérica que se pueda usar para concatenar hasta más de tres diccionarios?

---

**Actualizaciòn:**

Al final obtuve el siguiente código:

```
c = 0
results = []
for i in range(0, len(cups)):
    query = []
    for j in range(0, len(countries)):
        print('Append data ' + str(c))
        query.append(data[c])
        print(query[j])
        c += 1
    print (query)
    get_cup = itemgetter("cup")
    get_stats = itemgetter("stats")
    resultados.append([{"cup": cups[i], "stats": list(q["stats"] for q in qs)} for (cups[i], qs) in groupby(sorted(query, key=get_cup), key=get_cup)])
```

No sé si está limpio el código. ¿Se puede optimizar aún más?

Comment: ¿Todos los diccionarios comparten las mismas claves y todos los valores de las claves son iguales excepto para la clave `stats`?

Comment: En la pràctica si, dìgamos pongo los de copa 40 en un mismo diccionario, los de copa 41 en otro, pero todos tienen en comùn el mismo valor en ese campo.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Limitándome a responder a tu pregunta: los diccionarios **no se concatenan**. Lo que en realidad planteas es *concatenar* las listas que tienen los diccionarios en su clave `stats`. Más o menos así:

```
# cada pais es un diccionario con una clave "stats"
paises = [colombia, brasil, ecuador, peru]

resultado = { "cup":41,
              "stats": [pais["stats"] for pais in paises] }
```

---

**Editado**: considerar agrupaciones por la clave `cup`

Si lo que se quiere es juntar los diccionarios con el mismo valor de la clave `cup`:

```
# cada pais es un diccionario con una clave "stats"
paises = [colombia, brasil, ecuador, peru]

# set de todas las "cups"
cups = set(pais["cup"] for pais in paises)

resultado = [{ "cup": cup,
               "stats": [pais["stats"] for pais in paises
                                       if pais["cup"] == cup }
               for cup in cups ]
```

Otro método más complicado, pero que personalmente prefiero si son muchos diccionarios a procesar:

```
from operator import itemgetter
from itertools import groupby

paises = [colombia, brasil, ecuador, peru]
get_cup = itemgetter("cup")
get_stats = itemgetter("stats")
resultados = [
   { "cup": cup,
     "stats": list(p["stats"] for p in ps) }
  for (cup, ps) in groupby(sorted(paises, key=get_cup), key=get_cup) ]
```

---

**Variación**: supongamos que queremos un diccionario, teniendo en cada item las estadísticas de cada copa:

```
from operator import itemgetter
from itertools import groupby

paises = [colombia, brasil, ecuador, peru]
get_cup = itemgetter("cup")
get_stats = itemgetter("stats")
resultados = {
  cup: list(p["stats"] for p in ps) 
  for (cup, ps) in groupby(sorted(paises, key=get_cup), key=get_cup) }
```

Comment: Me surge este error en terminal: `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 4, in <module>
TypeError: string indices must be integers`. Adicionalmente, creo que todos los elementos en paìses deben estar entre comillas, sin comillas da error: `NameError: name 'Colombia' is not defined`.

Comment: La variable `paises` es una lista de diccionarios. Por ejemplo, tienes definido: `colombia = {'stats': [{'value': [{'wins': 3}, {'ties': 1}, {'defeats': 2}], 'team': 'Colombia'}], 'cup': 41}`

Comment: Ah, ya entendi, un momento haber si se ajusta a lo que necesito.

Efectivamente, pero aùn me falta un ùltimo paso, no se si por reglas lo puedo poner acà o debo hacer otra pregunta.

Comment: Perfecto, podrìas agregar como hacer un diccionario en vez de una lista pero obteniendo màs de un resultado? Es decir, tengo esos paìses pero diferentes copas y voy a meter todos los resultados en un diccionario.

Comment: Añado una variación de la solución, a ver si he entendido lo que pides. Pero no es bueno extender la respuesta más allá de lo necesario para responder a la pregunta original. Tendrías que haber probado a hacerlo tú primero y, después de probar, hacer una nueva pregunta con las dificultades que hayas tenido.

Comment: Ententido. Te ganaste esos puntos.